# setOnItemClickListener not activating in ListView Android

Tags: listview, android-cursoradapter

There is no actions in setOnItemClickListener, what is wrong in listView?
The View appearing, but not active.
No errors, not pushing, not reaction on clicking.
What should I create else or how to connect view with listView?

Fragment class

```
ListView listView;
CursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
View view = inflater.inflate(layout, container, false);
listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(list);
cursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(R.layout.listitem, getActivity(), null, true);
listView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view1, position, id) -> someActions(id));
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener((adapterView, view1, i, l) -> {
            ask(view1, i, l);
            return true;
        });
```

layout xml
with list id

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/list"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

listitem xml
with include list_item_c

```
<ru.rambler.libs.swipe_layout.SwipeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:left_swipe_enabled="true"
    app:right_swipe_enabled="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/list_item_c" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--RIGHT-->
    <include layout="@layout/undo_layout" />

    <include layout="@layout/mark_layout" />
</ru.rambler.libs.swipe_layout.SwipeLayout>
```

list_item_c
the main menu items

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textFrom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/attachemt"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textFrom"
        android:contentDescription="@string/flag"
        app:srcCompat="?attr/iconFlagForwarded"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/selected"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textFrom" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: setOnItemClickListener not working, then I m clicking on the field

Comment: Right, but briefly, what are you trying to do functionally?

Comment: i have such structure as a  Fragment.class, and layout with ListView. And i have the text fields which i need to implement in this ListView in xml list_item_c. I'm putting in cursorAdapter listitem with include my  list_item_c. They all appears on the screen, TextView and ImageView, but then i'm clicking on the ListView, to make some next actions, setOnItemClickListener not catch my clicking.

Comment: maybe it is because of SwipeLayout?

Comment: Not sure. but have you tried logging out from the listener you set to see if it's being hit at all?